# How to get a Cordova app running on the device to connect to Node JS server

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova

I have a nodeJS server running on my local machine and a Cordova app (hybrid). I am able to connect and run the app using the iOS simulator, however, it does not connect to the nodeJS server on my local machine when the app is installed on my iPhone.

Can you give some hints on how to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to configure network security. Here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the same local network, you can run `ipconfig` (if on windows) or `ifconfig` (if on unix) to find out your local machine IP address on the local network.
For example your address may be  192.168.0.2 and your node app runs on port 8080, in this instance you can use `192.168.0.2:8080` to access your server.

An easier and better way would be to use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create a tunnel to your local machine accessible from the internet.